# Ubuntu 19.10 has white calendar in top bar even when using yaru dark theme

Tags: 19.10

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and all work good but I have a little problem. Some elements in top bar have white color instead dark.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those white menus are the GNOME Shell theme, and not the GTK+ (applications) theme, and that's how Ubuntu 19.10 looks by default. Changing the GTK+ theme to Yaru Dark doesn't affect this. If you don't like those white menus, you'll need to change the  Shell theme, not the GTK+ theme.

If you want to get dark menus and dialogs with the Yaru GNOME Shell theme, see [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/10/how-to-get-dark-gnome-shell-menus-and.html) guide.